# Find and Move Data From One Column To Another in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a database column like

```
id, title, phone, email, wesbite
```

Since there some issue in data entry, phone column contains some email address which I want to move to email column, I am able to find all rows from phone column using below query

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE phone LIKE '%@%'
```

But I do not know how to move ( NOT Copy ) to it in the email column.

Comment: Maybe you can first copy then remove... which is the same at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `update` statement:

```
update data 
set email = phone, phone = null
where phone like '%@%'
```

For the selected rows, this sets `email` from `phone`, and sets `phone` to `null`.

It should be noted that in MySQL - unlike most other databases - the ordering of the assignments is important in such a query. If we were to assign a `null` value to `phone` first, then it would propagate to `email`.